# Nested divs with flexDirection: column; show vertical scroll bar on inner div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have such setup which works fine:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div
      style={{
        display: "flex",
        height: "100%",
        flexDirection: "column"
      }}
    >
      <div style={{ height: 50 }}>results</div>
      <div
        style={{
          flex: 1,
          background: "gray",
          display: "flex",
          flexDirection: "column"
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is screenshot:

[image]

You can see grey rectangle **correctly calculated vertical flex.**

As you can see I also plan to put some content inside gray div, hence `display:flex` and `flexDirection:column` inside.

Now look at this code:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div
      style={{
        display: "flex",
        height: "100%",
        flexDirection: "column"
      }}
    >
      <div style={{ height: 50 }}>results</div>
      <div
        style={{
          flex: 1,
          background: "gray",
          display: "flex",
          flexDirection: "column"
        }}
      >
        <div style={{ height: 100 }} />
        <div style={{ flex: 1, overflow: "auto" }}>
          {/* Just generates 1000 divs */}
          {new Array(1000).fill(null).map(x => (
            <div>test</div>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**My goal was as you can see that a vertical scrollbar appears when the content overflows the div with green border**, but instead the vertical scrollbar appears on the main page as seen on this screenshot:

[image]

How to achieve that vertical scrollbar is shown on the div with green border, using such setup?

Comment: add `min-height:0` to the div next the one containing `results` (the one with gray background)

Comment: @TemaniAfif Can you please explain why this works?

Comment: I added a duplicate link with the needed details